# std::convertible_to failing to recognize explicitly convertible types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, compiler-explorer

According to en.cppreference.com in [convertible_to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to):

> The concept convertible_to<From, To> specifies that an expression of the same type and value category as those of std::declval() can be implicitly and explicitly converted to the type To, and the two forms of conversion are equivalent.

I Understood this to mean that `convertible_to` concept will identify `convertible_to<U, V>` as satisfied if `U` has a member `explicit operator V()`. Even if the operator is explicit and not an implicit operator.

However I have discovered that this is not the case in msvc.

The following code fails to compile due to the static assert:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

class ExplictClass
{
public:
    inline explicit operator int() const
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::convertible_to<ExplictClass, int>, "Explicit not convertible?"); // Fails here, concept not satisfied.
}
```

Is this a misunderstanding I have about the concept `std::convertible_to`, an error in the code, or error in en.cppreference.com, or Non-conformance of msvc v19.

Attached link to compiler explorer with above code using x64 msvc v19.latest

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+ExplictClass%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++inline+explicit+operator+int()+const%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+5%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++static_assert(std::convertible_to%3CExplictClass,+int%3E,+%22Explicit+not+convertible%3F%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.50026164311878,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.49973835688121,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

**EDIT:**

The actual need for `convertible_to` was to generate a `to_string` function template that works well with castable types declared as so:

```
template<class T>
std::string to_string(T val)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << val;
    return stream.str();
}

template<Convertible<std::string> T>
std::string to_string(T val)
{
    return static_cast<std::string>(val);
}
```

Here I want types like `const char*`, `char*`, a type like `ExplicitClass` (with `explicit operator std::string`) all to use the second method, with the first method being a fallback option

Comment: `convertible_to` requires _both_ implicit and explicit conversions to be possible. Essentially, it requires implicit conversion and explicit follows. For explicit-only check is `constructible_from`

Comment: If a type has implicit conversion does it not by default also have explicit conversion?

Comment: Yes, but if something has explicit conversion it doesn't necessarily have implicit conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) requires *both* implicit *and* explicit conversion<sup>1)</sup>.
This can be seen in the definition:

```cpp
template <class From, class To>
concept convertible_to =
  std::is_convertible_v<From, To> &&                   // implicit conversion
  requires { static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>()); }; // explicit conversion
```

<sup>1)</sup> *Note: implicit convertibility almost always implies explicit convertibility*

Your `ExplicitClass` only has an explicit conversion to `int`, meaning that you can write `ExplicitClass(0)`, but it would not be possible to write `ExplicitClass e = 0;`, which requires an implicit conversion.

If you want a concept which tests whether `ExplicitClass` can be *explicitly* converted to `int`, you have two options:

#### A - Use just the explicit part of `std::convertible_to`

```cpp
template <class From, class To>
concept explicitly_convertible_to = requires {
    static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>());
};

// assertion passes
static_assert(explicitly_convertible_to<ExplictClass, int>);

// constraint satisfied for T = ExplicitClass
template <explicitly_convertible_to<int> T>
int foo(T t);
```

#### B: Use `std::constructible_from`

```cpp
// assertion passes
static_assert(std::constructible_from<int, From>);

// constraint satisfied for T = ExplicitClass
template <typename T>
requires std::constructible_from<int, T>
int foo(T t);
```

Note that [`std::constructible_from<To, From>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from) will test whether:

- [`std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<To>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible), and
- `To obj(From)` is well-formed, which is a weaker form of `static_cast<To>(From)` (both are [direct initializaton](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), but only `static_cast` can downcast pointers from `Base*` to `Derived*`, among other differences)

This means that `std::constructible_from` isn't equivalent to a `static_cast`, but it will do exactly what you want for class types like `ExplicitClass`.

Comment: @JeJo `static_cast<T>(...)` and `T(...)` are equivalent, so constructing and casting are somewhat interchangeable, at least for explicit conversion. `T(...)` also cannot be used when `T`'s destructor is deleted or private, so `std::constructible_from` is testing for the exact same thing as the `static_cast` requires expression. The only minute difference is that it also requires nothrow-destruction. Thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: @JanSchultke That's true for class types, but for other types `To(From)` allows more than `static_cast<To>(From)` does. E.g. if `To` is `int*` and `From` has type `long*`, then this will be equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @JanSchultke However, the actual check is for `To _(From);`, which indeed is always direct-initialization and weaker than `static_cast` (e.g. if `To` is `Derived*` and `From` has type `Base*`).

Comment: @user17732522 you cannot initialize an `int*` from a `long*` using direct initialization. `std::convertible_from<int*, long*>` is false. This looks to be the intended result to me. I wasn't aware of only `static_cast` being able to downcast pointers, that is a fair point.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yes, but the expression `To(From)` will still be valid, even though direct-initialization is not possible and `std::convertible_from` is false. That's different from the _declaration_ with initialization `To _(From);`, which is always direct-initialization.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for the corrections. I've updated the answer. I believe that `std::constructible_from` is still useful in this case, but the differences to `static_cast` validity need to be clear :)

Comment: @JanSchultke There are further differences, e.g. `static_cast` allows casting between scoped enumerations and integer types which direct-initialization doesn't. There is also conversion to `void` and conversion from `void*` to other pointer types.

Comment: @JanSchultke But I agree that one usually wants `std::constructible_from`. The `To(From)` syntax is too broad and I guess it would be surprising to most that it is equivalent to a C-style cast `(To)From` that would usually be considered dangerous for how broad it is.

Comment: Emphasizing "*both* implicit *and* explicit" strikes me as misleading - the main point is that `convertible_to` checks for implicit conversion and OP's conversion is explicit. Sure, it's literally possible to create a type that is implicitly, but not explicitly, convertible, and that would in fact cause `convertible_to` to fail, but nobody would ever do that.

Comment: @JanSchultke What I really actually need, is a concept such that when a template function is constrained with it. The function can use `static_cast<To>(obj)` where obj is an object of type From. Can I use `std::constructible_from` to accept all types where the above is possible?

Comment: @JanSchultke I will clarify the question

Comment: @WARhead I've added an example of how to use both concepts in type constraints. Just swap `int` for `std::string` or whatever other types you want to convert to. I recommend option A for this use case, because you can use it as a type constraint or in an abbreviated function template; `std::constructible_from` requires a `requires` clause.

Comment: @Barry I don't think nobody would ever do that intentionally, but it it's possible to create such a type by accident. Namely, you can have ambiguous overloads when using `explicit T` and `explicit Constructor(T)` are considered for overload resolution, but no ambiguity for implicit conversions. It's rare that this happens and most likely a mistake, but it's useful that `std::convertible_to` contains a "sanity check" that ensures both kinds of conversions are possible. I don't think it's misleading to keep this in mind, but I will rephrase the answer slightly.